# Create string to put in an IN statement from an array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, iteration

I have an array of arrays that look like this:

```
array(40) {
  [0]=>
    array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "ta"
    ["size"]=>
    int(2)
  [1]=>
    array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "tq"
    ["size"]=>
    int(4)
....
```

I want to be able to get all the sizes in a way that I can do a query like this:

```
IN (2,4)
```

so... For each array, get the size key: IN (size,size,size...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:-

```
$sizes = implode(',', array_map(function($v) { return $v['size']; }, $array));
```

Then just pass `$sizes` to your `IN` query

**edit**

In response to your comment below, you can use [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to remove duplicate sizes, eg:

```
$sizes = implode(',', array_unique(array_map(function($v) { return $v['size']; }, $array)));
```

Comment: Awesome! I fail to see how would I avoid having repeated sizes in the IN. Is that something you know how to do?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
$a = array("id"=>"ta","size"=>2);
$b = array("id"=>"tq","size"=>4);
$c = array($a,$b);

$in = array();
foreach ($c as $key=>$value) {
    if(array_key_exists("size", $value)){
        $in[] = $value["size"];
    }
}

echo implode(",", $in);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sizes = array();
foreach($array as $value) {
  $sizes[] = $value['size'];
}
$query = implode(',', $sizes);
```

query ...`" IN ($query) "`..